# Batch randomly crashes why?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

so i have narrowed it down to these lines of code, without them it doesn't crash, what is wrong with them? (the %DRIVE% is a user set varible already set before this point) (and the mm dd yy thing is set here):

```
set yy=%date:~10,4%
set mm=%date:~4,2%
set dd=%date:~7,2%

if exist "%DRIVE%:\MC\Logs\Log-%mm%-%dd%-%yy%.txt"
) else (
echo [Mobile Mc Log Data] > %DRIVE%:\MC\Logs\Log-%mm%-%dd%-%yy%.txt
)
echo [%TIME%] [%DATE%] - Log data that i will write later, >> "%DRIVE%:\MC\Logs\Log-%mm%-%dd%-%yy%.txt"
```

Comment: What does "crash" mean? please be more precise! What is your exact date format? may there occur spaces for on-digit numbers, like _space_ + `1`, or are there leading zeroes, like `01`? There is something missing after `if exist ...`, there should be a `(` and some command to execute. Put the redirection path after `>` in between `""`, just like you already do after `>>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if exist` code contains only the condition and lacks the command.

See below, the correct syntax:

`IF EXIST filename (command) ELSE (command`)

Comment: oh thank you, and i forgot the opening ( *facepalm*

Comment: You are welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

```
if exist "%DRIVE%:\MC\Logs\Log-%mm%-%dd%-%yy%.txt" (
    rem mismatched `IF` syntax
) else (
    rem use double quotes       ↓                                       ↓
    echo [Mobile Mc Log Data] > "%DRIVE%:\MC\Logs\Log-%mm%-%dd%-%yy%.txt"
)
```

or

```
if NOT exist "%DRIVE%:\MC\Logs\Log-%mm%-%dd%-%yy%.txt" (
    rem use double quotes       ↓                                       ↓
    echo [Mobile Mc Log Data] > "%DRIVE%:\MC\Logs\Log-%mm%-%dd%-%yy%.txt"
)
```

Moreover, The `%date%` could contain characters that are [not allowed in file names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Try next **locale-independent** approach:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions

for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"

set "_LocalDateTime=%_LocalDateTime:~0,8%"
set yy=%_LocalDateTime:~0,4%
set mm=%_LocalDateTime:~4,2%
set dd=%_LocalDateTime:~6,2%
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)